# Linking React Native (or any other framework) with Unity

Tags: android, ios, react-native, unity-game-engine, frameworks

So, I'm developing a mobile application in Unity and was wondering if it is possible to use it alongside React Native or any other framework in order to use UI elements for both iOS and Android with ease.

- What I mean here is to develop the entire UI within the framework and when I click a button, it opens the Unity application.

If the above question is possible, I would like to go even further and ask if I can "mix" the unity app with the UI from the framework and make them switch information

- Input form is inserted with the framework, the user types something
  and then unity gets that input and does something with it

Anxiously waiting for an answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you need to read this?

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary-iOS.html

Comment: @OnionFan That gave me a good direction, thanks!
Still have to study and figure it out how to make it work perfectly, but it's a good start.